# (re)detect number of monitors connected when disconnecting monitor

Tags: matlab

When multiple monitors are connected to my computer, I can detect them, and draw figures to them by setting the position according to the values obtained from

```
get(0, 'MonitorPositions')
```

However, when I disconnect a monitor while MATLAB is running, this property is not updated. I use [distFig](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37176-distribute-figures) to handle the positioning of the figures, but since this property is not updated, sometimes the figures are drawn at the pixel locations that lay outside my screen (i.e. drawing on my disconnected monitor).

Restarting MATLAB solves the issue, but is there a way to re-detect the number of monitors connected?

Comment: [According to the docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.root-properties.html#buc8_0n-MonitorPositions), the official answer would seem to be that restarting is the only way to update it. But I feel like maybe there could be some undocumented ways.

Comment: @gnovice yeah just came across that too, in [this](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/426269-get-0-monitorpositions-outputs-wrong-values) post the [WindowAPI](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31437-windowapi) is suggested, I'm trying to look into that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a solution using JAVA:

I got the JAVA code from here: [How do I get number of available screens?](https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-get-number-of-available-screens/)

Getting number of

`get(0, 'MonitorPositions')` keeps showing the same value, and the JAVA result changes:

```
%// Get local graphics environment
%GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
env = java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();

%// Returns an array of all of the screen GraphicsDevice objects.
%GraphicsDevice[] devices = env.getScreenDevices();
devices = env.getScreenDevices();

%numberOfScreens = devices.length;
numberOfScreens = length(devices)
```

---

I tested the code in Windows 10 OS.
In monitor duplicate mode, result is one monitor, and in extended mode 2.
When I unplug a monitor, the result is 1.
When unplugging all monitors the result is also 1 (it's not a perfect solution).

Comment: Awesome! Now I have a way to at least detect if the `MonitorPositions` value is correct, and select the right position value.

Comment: I am still hoping though that it is possible to call the routine that detects the monitor positions on startup to update `groot`, but I have a feeling that is impossible (since the monitor position is write protected).